# Android studio very slow gradle build

Tags: android

I'm new to Android Studio..whenever I run my project it takes around 14 mins for gradle build..I've check for solutions to improve build speed as mentioned in [here](https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2015/02/24/android-speed-up-gradle-build-process-in-android-studio/)

My gradle.properties file:

```
## Project-wide Gradle settings.

org.gradle.daemon=true

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

but the problem is still the same and each of these lines are dim in color just like they were comment lines code.
when the mouse is hovered on top there a message which says "Unused Property. This inspection reports all properties not referenced from outside of the properties file"

how can I fix this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 10):

make     `gradle.properties`file in `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle (Windows)`

then,Add this line to the file:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

Comment: What's the solution for Mac machine?

Comment: `/Users/<username>/.gradle/ (Mac)` try this location in MAC

Comment: when daemon  enables in gradel ,it allow some background services to improve build speed by reusing computations from previous builds.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for Linux/OSX may looks like this:

```
echo 'org.gradle.daemon=true' >> ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

echo 'org.gradle.configureondemand=true' >> ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

echo 'org.gradle.parallel=true' >> ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

echo 'org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' >> ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
```

Using these commands you make changes in global `gradle.properties` file.

More info (together with detailed explanation) can he found [here](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/making-gradle-builds-faster/).