# Gradle is loading really slow

Tags: android, android-studio

When I'm trying to run the project I'm waiting like 2-5 minutes for gradle to load. This has been happening for a couple of weeks now. I searched for solutions and found out about `Gradle offline`. I tried to search for it, under Settings-Build,Execution,Deployment - Compiler , but it is not there. I saw that on Mac that option is present. Is there another way to improve this gradle loading time ?

Comment: how much RAM have your pc?

Comment: check this link http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2015/06/11/speeding-up-your-gradle-builds/

Comment: `org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m` - these might help, but if I try to add them to the gradle.properties file nothing happens

Comment: Look this question, is equal as your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184675/android-studio-very-slow-gradle-build

Comment: thanks, that solved it

Comment: great @Bogdan Daniel

Comment: @Coeus I thought it solved it, but I just ran a project and it took 2 mins